# Convert numpy array of a image into blocks

Tags: python, numpy

I have of a numpy array of a image.I want to convert this image into 8*8 block using python.How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

reshape and then swapaxes:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(128, 256, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

blocks = img.reshape(img.shape[0]//8, 8, img.shape[1]//8, 8, 3).swapaxes(1, 2)
print(blocks.shape)
```

to check the result:

```
np.allclose(blocks[0, 0], img[:8, :8, :])
np.allclose(blocks[3, 2], img[3*8:3*8+8, 2*8:2*8+8, :])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your array structure.

you can use `img_arrary.reshape(8,8)`, to work total elements must be 64

Comment: In reshape function only get the whole image shaped.But I want to access the image data block by block.How sholud I do this?EX: It is needed to seperate whole image as seperate 8*8 pixel blocks.

Comment: you can use slicing or boolean masking. Just look at on Numpy Slicing tutorial, you will get it easily.